# Calculating $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{(x+a)^2+b^2}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

I have to prove that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{(x+a)^2+b^2}=\frac{\ln(\sqrt{a^2+b^2})}{b}\arctan(\frac{b}{a})$$
for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ using complex analysis.

I have to use the residue theorem and the Jordan's lemma. I know there is an answer here: [Contour integral for finding $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{(x+a)^2+b^2} \, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816892/contour-integral-for-finding-int-0-infty-frac-ln-xxa2b2-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1)
But in this answer don't use the form of Jordan's lemma, that is $\lim_{R \rightarrow\infty} \int_\gamma f(z)e^{i \lambda z}dz=0$ where $\lambda > 0$ and $\gamma$ is a family of circular arcs of radii $R$ and $Imz \geq a$.
I've tried using the function  $$g(z)=\frac{Ln(z)}{(z+a)^2+b^2}$$ and I found that the poles are $-a+ib$ and $-a-ib$. But from here I don't know how to continue to know which branch of the logarithm I should eliminate.
I would appreciate if someone helps me

Comment: I know you are being asked to use residue theorem, which is why this is a comment and not an answer, but you can do this integral without complex analysis. Simply use the substitution $xy = a^2+b^2$

Comment: Have you tried differentiating both sides?

Comment: If both derivatives are equal, that means that the original expressions are equal, or only differ by a constant

Comment: @NinadMunshi I have to solve this using the results that I've mentioned

Comment: Yes, it could be a solution, but I have to solve this using the Residue Theorem and the Jordan's lemma@SomeGuy

Comment: Instead of adopting a keyhole contour as your integration path, choose a semicircle on the upper half of the complex plane and remember that $log(z)$ for $z<0$ is equal to $log|-z|+πi$. Then, assuming that $b≠0$ you just need to compute the residue of $-a+bi$.