# How to show $\int_0^\infty \frac{t\ln x}{(x+1)^2+t^2}dx=\frac12\arctan(t)\ln(1+t^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3778656/prove-int-0-infty-frac-ln1x-arctan-sqrtx4x2-mathrmd), it mentions the following result without giving a proof.

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{t\ln x}{(x+1)^2+t^2}dx=\frac12\arctan(t)\ln(1+t^2)\tag{1}$$

I know how to compute the case for

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{t\ln x}{x^2+t^2}dx$$

after do the sub $x=ut$,

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{t\ln x}{x^2+t^2}dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln u}{u^2+1}du+\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln t}{u^2+1}du=0+\frac\pi2\ln t$$

But for (1) there is a shift for $x\to x+1$, and we can't use the way we did above. How should I prove this result? Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Check this: [Contour integral for finding $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{(x+a)^2+b^2} \, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1816892/42969)

Comment: Since this post has been closed, I wrote a [general solution here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816892/contour-integral-for-finding-int-0-infty-frac-ln-xxa2b2-dx) $$\int_0^\infty \frac{a\ln^n x}{(x+a)^2+b^2}~dx=\lim_{\color{red}s\to0}\frac{d^n}{d\color{red}s^n}\left(\frac{\pi(a^2+b^2)^{\color{red}s/2}\cdot\sin\left(\color{red}s\cdot \arctan\left(\frac ba\right) \right)}{\sin(\pi \color{red}s)}\right)$$

Answer (score 7):

Substitute $y=\frac{1+t^2}x$
\begin{align}
I=&\int_0^\infty \frac{t\ln x}{(x+1)^2+t^2}dx\\
= & \int_0^\infty \frac{t\ln(1+t^2)-t\ln y}{(y+1)^2+t^2}dy
= \int_0^\infty \frac{t\ln(1+t^2)}{(y+1)^2+t^2}dy-I\\
=& \ \frac12\ln(1+t^2) \int_0^\infty \frac{t}{(y+1)^2+t^2}dy
= \frac12\ln(1+t^2)\arctan(t)
\end{align}

Comment: Congratulations, nice solution ! (+1)

Comment: Since this post has been closed, I wrote a [general solution here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816892/contour-integral-for-finding-int-0-infty-frac-ln-xxa2b2-dx) $$\int_0^\infty \frac{a\ln^n x}{(x+a)^2+b^2}~dx=\lim_{\color{red}s\to0}\frac{d^n}{d\color{red}s^n}\left(\frac{\pi(a^2+b^2)^{\color{red}s/2}\cdot\sin\left(\color{red}s\cdot \arctan\left(\frac ba\right) \right)}{\sin(\pi \color{red}s)}\right)$$